# How to set up private tor network with a chutney

Tags: configuration, tor-browser-bundle, private

I am a Japanese university student. I believe that you want to create a private tow network with the chutney.I would like to be able to see the route using the Tor-Browser.How Could you tell me how to use and the optimal environment of chutney.

Environment of my machine is as follows:
virtual machine: VMwareplayer
OS:Lubuntu14.04

I have entered a command I get an error as follows:

> ~$ git clone https://git.torproject.org/chutney.git
>   Cloning into 'chutney'...
>   remote: Counting objects: 591, done.
>   remote: Compressing objects: 100% (376/376), done.
>   remote: Total 591 (delta 315), reused 277 (delta 137)
>   Receiving objects: 100% (591/591), 95.29 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
>   Resolving deltas: 100% (315/315), done.
>   Checking connectivity... done.
>
> ~$ cd chutney
>
> ~/chutney$ ./chutney configure networks/basic
>
> Using Python 2.7.6
>
> Creating identity key /home/j13187ys/chutney/net/nodes/000a/keys/authority_identity_key for test000a with tor-gencert --create-identity-key --passphrase-fd 0 -i /home/j13187ys/chutney/net/nodes/000a/keys/authority_identity_key -s /home/j13187ys/chutney/net/nodes/000a/keys/authority_signing_key -c /home/j13187ys/chutney/net/nodes/000a/keys/authority_certificate -m 12 -a 127.0.0.1:7000
>   Cannot find tor-gencert binary 'tor-gencert'. Use CHUTNEY_TOR_GENCERT environment variable to set the path, or put the binary into $PATH.
>
> ~/chutney$ sudo apt-get install tor
>
> ~/chutney$ ./chutney configure networks/basic
>
> Using Python 2.7.6
>   NOTE: renaming '/home/j13187ys/chutney/net/nodes' to '/home/j13187ys/chutney/net/nodes.1463765026'
>
> Creating identity key /home/j13187ys/chutney/net/nodes/000a/keys/authority_identity_key for test000a with tor-gencert --create-identity-key --passphrase-fd 0 -i /home/j13187ys/chutney/net/nodes/000a/keys/authority_identity_key -s /home/j13187ys/chutney/net/nodes/000a/keys/authority_signing_key -c /home/j13187ys/chutney/net/nodes/000a/keys/authority_certificate -m 12 -a 127.0.0.1:7000
>
> Creating identity key /home/j13187ys/chutney/net/nodes/001a/keys/authority_identity_key for test001a with tor-gencert --create-identity-key --passphrase-fd 0 -i /home/j13187ys/chutney/net/nodes/001a/keys/authority_identity_key -s /home/j13187ys/chutney/net/nodes/001a/keys/authority_signing_key -c /home/j13187ys/chutney/net/nodes/001a/keys/authority_certificate -m 12 -a 127.0.0.1:7001
>
> Creating identity key /home/j13187ys/chutney/net/nodes/002a/keys/authority_identity_key for test002a with tor-gencert --create-identity-key --passphrase-fd 0 -i /home/j13187ys/chutney/net/nodes/002a/keys/authority_identity_key -s /home/j13187ys/chutney/net/nodes/002a/keys/authority_signing_key -c /home/j13187ys/chutney/net/nodes/002a/keys/authority_certificate -m 12 -a 127.0.0.1:7002
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteExit *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteHSDir *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteGuard *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'Sandbox 1'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingServerDownloadSchedule 0, 5'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingServerConsensusDownloadSchedule 0, 5'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteExit *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteHSDir *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteGuard *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'Sandbox 1'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingServerDownloadSchedule 0, 5'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingServerConsensusDownloadSchedule 0, 5'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteExit *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteHSDir *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteGuard *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'Sandbox 1'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingServerDownloadSchedule 0, 5'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingServerConsensusDownloadSchedule 0, 5'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteExit *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteHSDir *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteGuard *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'Sandbox 1'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingServerDownloadSchedule 0, 5'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingServerConsensusDownloadSchedule 0, 5'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteExit *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteHSDir *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteGuard *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'Sandbox 1'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingServerDownloadSchedule 0, 5'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingServerConsensusDownloadSchedule 0, 5'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteExit *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteHSDir *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteGuard *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'Sandbox 1'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingServerDownloadSchedule 0, 5'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingServerConsensusDownloadSchedule 0, 5'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteExit *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteHSDir *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteGuard *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'Sandbox 1'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingServerDownloadSchedule 0, 5'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingServerConsensusDownloadSchedule 0, 5'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteExit *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteHSDir *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteGuard *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'Sandbox 1'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingServerDownloadSchedule 0, 5'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingServerConsensusDownloadSchedule 0, 5'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteExit *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteHSDir *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteGuard *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'Sandbox 1'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingClientDownloadSchedule 0, 5'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingClientConsensusDownloadSchedule 0, 5'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteExit *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteHSDir *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingDirAuthVoteGuard *'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'Sandbox 1'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingClientDownloadSchedule 0, 5'
>
> The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line:
>   'TestingClientConsensusDownloadSchedule 0, 5'

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an *actual* versions of Tor in your system, it's all in your error logs. You have basically/mostly two types of error:

- **binary not found** - you're missing `tor-gencert` in message

  > Cannot find tor-gencert binary 'tor-gencert'. Use CHUTNEY_TOR_GENCERT environment variable to set the path, or put the binary into $PATH.
- **Tor binary is old/improper version** - in all the messages like

  > The tor binary at 'tor' does not support the option in the torrc line: 'the-line-tor-does-not-understands-in-it's-config'

Use a binary from Tor Git, it seems to be hitting [an old bug of tor](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/13161) - it's already fixed. Confirmed in [chutney source code itself](https://github.com/torproject/chutney/blob/master/torrc_templates/authority.i) :

> # Work around situations where the Exit, Guard and HSDir flags aren't being set
>
> # These flags are all set eventually, but it takes Guard up to ~30 minutes
>
> # We could be more precise here, but it's easiest just to vote everything
>
> # Clients are sensible enough to filter out Exits without any exit ports,
>
> # and Guards and HSDirs without ORPorts
>
> # If your tor doesn't recognise TestingDirAuthVoteExit/HSDir,
>
> # either update your chutney to a 2015 version,
>
> # or update your tor to a later version, most likely 0.2.6.2-final